# How to change color of background in HTML?

Tags: html, css

[image: Screenshot added:]

I am doing my stuff in HTML and css and i want to change background color into grey color of red marked places. I have tried everything margin and all.And here is my website coding
https://www.datafilehost.com/d/5da9de9a

Comment: Does that also happen in IE or is it just Chrome?

Comment: For this question you need to show your HTML and CSS, and show, in the code, which area(s) you want to change the `background-color` property on.

Comment: https://www.datafilehost.com/d/5da9de9a @Daivd

Comment: No, include your [MCVE] code *in your question* otherwise, as soon as your question is fixed the reproduction of the problem is no longer present. This makes your question useless and nonsensical for any others in future that might experience the same, or similar, problems.

Answer (score 0):

-- Pure html --

add `style="color:<YOUR COLOUR>` on your body.

-- CSS --

On body : add `class="<YOUR CLASS NAME>"`

In linked CSS file: `.<YOUR CLASS NAME> {color : <YOUR COLOR> }`

Comment: See my html and css i have done this thing its about padding and marfin and i dont know accurate for this https://www.datafilehost.com/d/5da9de9a

Comment: Download does not work on Chrome. Also: David Thomas is right. Add your html, css to the post and we'll be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add gray color all over the body the just all this

```
<!-- styling in inline HTML  -->
<body style="background: #F2F2F2">
<div style="background: #F2F2F2">

<!-- styling in css by selecting class  -->
body{
    background: #F2F2F2;
}
.your-class-of-the-selected-area{
    background: #F2F2F2;
}
```

Comment: Bro i know this things just download my html and css file from the link and see it your self

Comment: add your html and css here that will be better to solve the problem